# Multiple Paths Traversed and Displayed Filed type in Maya Menu with Python

Tags: python, menu, directory, maya

I'm new here so bare in mind that and I hope my questions are clearly asked for you lot to help me out. I am trying to alter Brent Tylers Dropbox script so that I will be able to list Python under Python, Mel under Mel and so on(eventually plugins and other files too but not for now)

Ok so my directory is like so:

```
1.
sf=C:/users/scripts/ a.py + b.mel
pf=C:/users/scripts/Python/c.py
mf=C:/users/scripts/Mel/d.mel
```

(These are the folders my scripts will be placed in)

Code :

```
absoluteFiles = []
relativeFiles = []
folders = []
allFiles = []
currentFile = ''

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sf):
    for x in files:
        correct = root.replace('\\', '/')
        currentFile = (correct + '/' + x)
        allFiles.append(currentFile)
        if currentFile.endswith('.mel'):
            relativeFiles.append(currentFile.replace((mf + '/'), ""))
        if currentFile.endswith('.py'):
            relativeFiles.append(currentFile.replace((pf + '/'), ""))

relativeFiles.sort()

for relativeFile in relativeFiles:
    split = relativeFile.split('/')
    fileName = split[-1].split('.')
    i=0
    while i<(len(split)):
        ### Create Folders ###
        if i==0 and len(split) != 1:
            if cmds.menu(split[i] ,ex=1) == 0:
                cmds.menuItem(split[i], p=PadraigsTools, bld=1, sm=1, to=1, l=split[i])
        if i > 0 and i < (len(split)-1):
            if cmds.menu(split[i] ,ex=1) == 0:
                cmds.menuItem(split[i], p=split[i-1], bld=1, sm=1, to=1, l=split[i])

        ### Create .mel Files  ###
        if fileName[-1] == 'mel':
            if i==len(split)-1 and len(split) > 1:
                scriptName = split[-1].split('.')
                temp1 = 'source ' + '"' + sf + '/' + relativeFile + '"; ' + scriptName[0]
                command = '''mel.eval(''' + "'" + temp1 + '''')'''
                cmds.menuItem(split[i], p=split[i-1], c=command, l=split[i])
            if i==len(split)-1 and len(split) == 1:
                scriptName = split[-1].split('.')
                temp1 = 'source ' + '"' + sf + '/' + relativeFile + '"; ' + scriptName[0]
                command = '''mel.eval(''' + "'" + temp1 + '''')'''
                cmds.menuItem(split[i], p=Mel, c=command, l=split[i])

        ### Create .py Files  ###
        if fileName[-1] == 'py':
            if i==len(split)-1 and len(split) > 1:
                command = 'import ' + fileName[0] + '\n' + fileName[0] + '.' + fileName[0]+ '()'
                cmds.menuItem(split[i], p=split[i-1], c=command, l=split[i])
            if i==len(split)-1 and len(split) == 1:
                command = 'import ' + fileName[0] + '\n' + fileName[0] + '.' + fileName[0]+ '()'
                cmds.menuItem(split[i], p=Python, c=command, l=split[i])
        i+=1
```

2. So far I can print out individually (sf, pf, mf) to the corresponding Directory but I cant list out everything at once and the files under sf will not show at all. regarding the folders created it ends up very odd. sometimes i would get a duplicate folder as a submenu and if i use sf it give me C:/.
3. After days and hours of research trying to mend this script I have found no answer including

`from itertools import chain
paths = (mf, sf, pf)
for path, dirs, files in chain.from_iterable(os.walk(path) for path in paths):`

**::QUESTION::**
Is there a way i can put this together sanely so that new folders will show up with their contents on refresh as a submenu and the files will show up and allow me to execute them from their corresponding submenu.

I would appreciate any help possible including down votes haha. And bare in mind I don't want you to hand me the answer on a golden spoon because I wont know what is corrected or needs to be :)

Thanks Greatly
-- Padraig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things you can do to simplify things a bit.

First, it's a good idea to make this as data-driven as possible so you don't have to re-write it if your needs change. This does more or less what you do, but collects the results into a dictionary where the key are the root paths you supplied and the values are lists of relative paths:

```
def find_files(root, extensions = ('mel', 'py')):
    def clean_path(*p):
        return "/".join(p).replace('\\', '/')

    for root, _, files in os.walk(root):
        used = [f for f in files if f.split(".")[-1] in extensions]
        for u in used:
            yield clean_path(root, u)

def relativize(abs, roots):
    low_roots = map (str.lower, roots) # all lower for comparison
    for root, low_root in zip(roots,low_roots):
        if abs.lower().startswith(low_root):
            return root, abs[len(root):]
    return ("", abs)


relative_paths = find_files('c:/users/scripts')

root_dict = {}
for item in relative_paths :
    folder, file = relativize(item, ('C:/users/scripts/Python/', 'C:/users/scripts/Mel/', 'C:/users/scripts/'))
    if not folder in root_dict:
        root_dict[folder] = []
    root_dict[folder].append(file)
```

So now you have a dictionary with a bunch of root folders and lists of relative paths (files that were not in any relative path you supplied are keyed to empty string and show up as absolute paths).  You can make the menus in a very generic way because they are all in the same format.  If you need the entire list, you can get it like this:

```
 results = []
 for each_root in root_dict:
     for relpath in root_dict[each_root]:
         results.append(each_root + relpath)
```

For creating the actual menus, you want to use a single function and bind it to the filename for each menu item as you make it. This is a slightly tricky topic (more detail [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html)).  The easy way to do this is to use a `functools.partial` object, which bundles a command and a bunch of arguments into an object which looks like a function: you can create a partial and attach it to the command of your menu items so they all call the same function with their individual arguments.  Here's a simple example using the variables from above and a menubar; you can see how to adapt it to other kinds of menus pretty easily:

```
from functools import partial

# call this on every button selection
def test(filepath, ignore):
    # maya will send "test(name, False)"; we just ignore the 'False'
    print "Here's where I would reload", filepath

example = cmds.window(title = 'example')
menubar = cmds.menuBarLayout()            

for name in folder_names:
    menuname = name
    if menuname:
        menuname = menuname.split("/")[-2] # we used trailing slashes
    else:
        menuname = "root"
    cmds.menu(label = menuname)
    file_names = root_dict[name]
    file_names.sort()
    for fn in file_names:
        mi = cmds.menuItem(label = fn, command = partial(test, fn))
    cmds.setParent(menubar)
```

Comment: Ok so I am a little confused but I will try explain your code

1. find_files = py and mel, create a clean path and change the \\ to /, all stringed are changed to lower for comparison, relative_paths is assigned to find_files in a dictionary file. This looks for the mel and py files and appends it to the name, if not it just gets into a array

Comment: for the menu do i keep my basic layout or create another under your code. its basically just a normal menu and menuitems with labels menu. The functools.partial I kind of grasped after hitting up the link you commented. IT gets loaded in instead of a c = "do this code" if im not mistaken. haha I think i need alot more help

Comment: The first chunk finds mel and py files under a root directory; the second takes a list of sub-directories you care about and sorts the files into relative paths under those; the third returns that as a dictionary with the root folders as keys and the relative paths as values.

The last  part makes a menu out of the dictionary. Every item in the menu runs the same script, but will be passed a file path that reflects the menu item. The actual loading/unloading/running of the script should go into that function.  The partial is just bundles an argument and a function without all that string stuff

Comment: appended it to my menu successfully but now all the files are just listed under other and not sorted by sub menu

Comment: you can check the data by looking at the dictionary: if you're getting only one key you might have a typo in the paths you feed to relativize

Comment: ok so the dictionary prints out correctly all the files listed, Im just having a little trouble still putting .py files under the python sub menu and .mel under the Mel sub menu. But over all I love how simple you've created it compared to how it was.

Comment: Im still finding it awkward trying to append the .mel and .py files to the sub dirs lol, I can get it to list out correctly but when i try this

`for f in files:
          if f.endswith(".py"):
              cmds.setParent("MayaWindow|PadraigsTools|Python")`

I get no object matches Python error