# Maya Python - attaching dictionary files to already created submenus

Tags: python, file, menu, traversal, maya

OK so I have a menubar parented to mainWindow set up in maya written in python. I also have 3 folders with with Mel and Python Files in them.

`folder_names = C:/scriptsFolder/c.mel + d.py
               C:/scriptsFolder/Mel/a.mel
               C:/scriptsFolder/Python/b.py`

I have had help on this subject before by @theodox but for this question and he helped me create a dictionary file, but when he integrated `funtools-partial` for the menu he showed me instead of grabbing those files from the dictionary that was created his menubar added the names of the corresponding physical folder to the menubar and listed the files under the menu. This is a really great idea for somethings but not for what I need it for. I need the output from the dictionaryfiles listed under their already created MenuItem.

The previous post is here: [Multiple Paths Traversed and Displayed Filed type in Maya Menu with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484036/multiple-paths-traversed-and-displayed-filed-type-in-maya-menu-with-python)

Thanks for your help in advance and @theodox if you are lookig thank you for your help aswell :)

```
import os
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

# Location of Folders

folder_names = ['C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Python Code'
                'C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Mel Code'
                'C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/']

# Delete the Menu if it already exists
if cmds.menu('PadraigsTools', exists = True):
    cmds.deleteUI('PadraigsTools')

#Creating the GUI
PadraigsTools=cmds.menu('PadraigsTools', p='MayaWindow', label='PadraigsTools')

# The Refresh Function / Refresh the scripts
cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, l="Refresh", c='PadraigsTools')
cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, d=1)

# Browse through Directories
cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, l="Change")
cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, d=1)

Python = cmds.menuItem(subMenu=1, label='Python', c=test)
cmds.setParent(Python, menu=True )
cmds.menuItem( label='pythonFileList.py')

Mel = cmds.menuItem(subMenu=1,label='Mel',p='PadraigsTools',c=test())
cmds.setParent( Mel, menu=True)
cmds.menuItem (label='melFileList.mel')

Plugins = cmds.menuItem(subMenu=1,label='Plugins',p='PadraigsTools', c=test)
cmds.setParent( Plugins, menu=True)
cmds.menuItem (label='Plugin.mll')

Other = cmds.menuItem(subMenu=1,label='Other',p='PadraigsTools', c=test)
cmds.setParent( Other, menu=True)
cmds.menuItem (label='Other')


# Searching for Mel and Python Files
def find_files(root, extensions = ('mel', 'py')):
    def clean_path(*p):
        return "/".join(p).replace('\\', '/')

    for root, _, files in os.walk(root):
        used = [f for f in files if f.split(".")[-1] in extensions]
        for u in used:
            yield clean_path(root, u)
# Creating a dictionary with given files
def relativize(abs, roots):
    low_roots = map (str.lower, roots) # all lower for comparison
    for root, low_root in zip(roots,low_roots):
        if abs.lower().startswith(low_root):
            return root, abs[len(root):]
    return "", abs

relative_paths = find_files('C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/')

root_dict = {}
for item in relative_paths :
    folders, files = relativize(item, ('C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Python Code','C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Mel Code', 'C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts'))
    if not folders in root_dict:
        root_dict[folders] = []
    root_dict[folders].append(files)

# call this on every button selection
def test(filepath, ignore):
    # maya will send "test(name, False)"; we just ignore the 'False'
    print "Here's where I would reload", filepath

for name in folder_names:
    PadraigsTools = name
    if PadraigsTools:
        PadraigsTools = PadraigsTools.split("/")[-2] # we used trailing slashes
    else:
        PadraigsTools = "root"
    file_names = root_dict[name]
    file_names.sort()
    for fn in file_names:
        mi = cmds.menuItem(label = fn, command = partial(test, fn))
        cmds.setParent(Python)
```

Ok so with this it tells me that Python isn't available but it clearly directs you to it via the Path `MayaWindow|PadraigsTools|menuItem1345` or if I label it `MayaWindow|PadraigsTools|Python`

-Padraig

Comment: hmmm aparently noboby knows haha

Comment: What's your code? I guess that you've made some modifications since your last question. Please provide a working example of what you currently have.

Comment: Just edited and added the code thanks DrHaze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way of doing it all myself. If there is a more pythonic way of approaching this I would love to see suggestions.

```
import os
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

# Location of Folders

folder_names = ('C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Python Code',
                'C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Mel Code',
                'C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts')

# Delete the Menu if it already exists
if cmds.menu('PadraigsTools', exists = True):
    cmds.deleteUI('PadraigsTools')

#Creating the GUI
PadraigsTools=cmds.menu('PadraigsTools', p='MayaWindow', label='PadraigsTools')

# The Refresh Function / Refresh the scripts
cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, l="Refresh", c='PadraigsTools')
cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, d=1)

# Browse through Directories
cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, l="Change")
cmds.menuItem(p=PadraigsTools, d=1)

Python = cmds.menuItem("Python",subMenu=1, label='Python')
cmds.setParent(Python, menu=True )
cmds.menuItem(label ='Python Files')

Mel = cmds.menuItem("Mel", subMenu=1, label='Mel', p='PadraigsTools')
cmds.setParent( Mel, menu=True)
cmds.menuItem (label='melFileList.mel')

Plugins = cmds.menuItem("Plugins", subMenu=1, label='Plugins', p='PadraigsTools')
cmds.setParent( Plugins, menu=True)
cmds.menuItem (label='Plugin.mll')

Other = cmds.menuItem("Other", subMenu=1, label='Other', p='PadraigsTools')
cmds.setParent( Other, menu=True)
cmds.menuItem (label='Other', p=Other)

# Searching for Mel and Python Files
def find_files(root, extensions = ('mel', 'py')):
    def clean_path(*p):
        return "/".join(p).replace('\\', '')

    for root, _, files in os.walk(root):
        used = [f for f in files if f.split(".")[-1] in extensions]
        for u in used:
            yield clean_path(root, u)
# Creating a dictionary with given files
def relativize(abs, roots):
    low_roots = map (str.lower, roots) # all lower for comparison
    for root, low_root in zip(roots,low_roots):
        if abs.lower().startswith(low_root):
            return root, abs[len(root):]
    return "", abs

relative_paths = find_files('C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/')

root_dict = {}
for item in relative_paths :
    folders, files = relativize(item, ('C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Python Code','C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts/Mel Code', 'C:/Users/OCuinn/Dropbox/Maya Scripts'))
    if not folders in root_dict:
        root_dict[folders] = []
    root_dict[folders].append(files)

# call this on every button selection
def test(filepath, ignore):
    # maya will send "test(name, False)"; we just ignore the 'False'
    print "Here's where I would reload", filepath

for name in folder_names:
    PadraigsTools = name
    if PadraigsTools:
        PadraigsTools = PadraigsTools.split("/")[-2] # we used trailing slashes
    else:
        PadraigsTools = "root"
    cmds.menu(label = PadraigsTools)
    file_names = root_dict[name]
    file_names.sort()
    for fn in file_names:
        if fn.endswith(".py"):
            cmds.menuItem(label = fn, p="Python", command = partial(test, fn))
        else:
            if fn.endswith(".mel"):
                    cmds.menuItem(label = fn, p="Mel", command = partial(test, fn))
```